# Calling a GraphQL API over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, graphql

I was able to make a graphql POST from Postman by choosing "GraphQL" content type:

[image]

When I am trying to perform the POST from C#:

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/graphql";
            myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
            
            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

            var newStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        string strContent = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                        return strContent;
                    }
                }
            }
```

it looks the the content type is expected to be application/json even I specifically set content type to be "application/graphql" because the response I get is:

```
{"data":null,"errors":[{"message":"failed to recognize JSON request: 'invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of value'","path":null,"extensions":{"timestamp":"2021-05-19T16:04:23.091659509Z"}}]}
```

How can I rewrite this part as json?

```
query{
viewer{
    accounts(filter: {accountTag: "accountTagHere"}){
        ipFlows1mGroups(
            limit:10
            filter: {datetimeMinute_gt: "2021-05-19T16:00:00Z"}){
                avg{bitsPerSecond}
            }
    }
}
```

}

This doens't work:

```
var postParams = @"{`query`:`viewer{accounts(filter: { accountTag: ...";
postParams = postParams.Replace("`", "\"");
```

Comment: There's a spec that's formalizing in the community here:
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-over-http

Else you've got the original best practice from Facebook here: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/

Comment: @benmccallum, saw the second link, but I don't know how to encode "viewer { account {...". This didn't work:
var postParams = @"{`query`:`viewer{accounts(filter: { accountTag: `...";
postParams = postParams.Replace("`", "\"");

Comment: You need to post a bit of the C# code so we can see what you're doing. How are you setting up the request and setting the body?

Comment: If you're writing a string with `@`, you can use `""` around the JSON object's property names. But if you want to build up JSON, then you need to post as `application/json` and you should probably have a GraphQLRequest class that you'd POST. At this point, I'd suggest graphql-dotnet/graphql-client on GitHub, but I'd honestly take a look at StrawberryShake, it's amazing.

Comment: If you're determined to use HttpClient direct, you should be aware of https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/ too, which has `PostAsJsonAsync<T>` methods if you were to create a GraphQLRequest class as it'll serialize it for you and handle setting the body on the request message. Problem is that `Variables` is a tricky one being an array of `object`, so again, the abstraction libraries I've linked are your friend.

Comment: @benmccallum, 
- I added C# code
- I cannot use another library, this code will be called from CLR, so I cannot complicate the things.
- I saw your link, but the question is how to rewrite graphql payload in json. Please see the payload in the post: "query { viewer { ...} }". What is the operation name in my case?

Comment: Adding graphql-client would still be my recommendation, it supports net461 and netstandard2.0. Anyway, the code you've got is still mixing methods of talking to a gql server. You're setting the content type as `application/graphql` but trying to build JSON by the looks. Try `client.UploadString(uri, "query { viewer { ... } }");` and continue using `application/graphql`. It could also be possible that the server you're posting to doesn't support `application/graphql` though, don't forget.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `application/graphql`, according to the original guidelines from Facebook [here](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request), the body of the POST should be the query and only the query, just as you've got in your Postman screenshot. You shouldn't need to encode it, just set the body using `StringContent` (assuming you're using `HttpClient`).

Another option though is to POST using `application/json` and then you need to post JSON of the form as shown on that page and below. (Note: make sure to use an `operationName` that matches the one in the `query`, or just not pass it if you've got only one and it's not named)

```json
{
  "query": "...",
  "operationName": "...",
  "variables": { "myVariable": "someValue", ... }
}
```

Finally, why not use a library that makes this easier for you? There's options for GraphQL C# client's.

- [StrawberryShake](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/) - Generates typed clients from .graphql files and can have a store backing it (think redux) that caches/syncs data, supports reactive concepts, etc. More [here](https://chillicream.com/blog/2021/03/31/chillicream-platform-11-1/#strawberry-shake). There's even [a VS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChilliCream.strawberryshake-visualstudio) that gives you intellisense when writing your queries.
- [graphql-dotnet/graphql-client](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client) - A simple wrapper around HttpClient